# get source IP consuming storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I need to know the source IP that are accessing one storage account. Is this possible?

For example, I see that "GetBlobProperties" transaction appears more than 400 millions per day. So I need to know who is consuming...

I searched in storage account metrics, but I cannot find where are they coming from.

Also searched in google but nobody has the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you enabled diagnostics logs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging btw, are you using your blob storage for checkpointing of a Kafka or EventHub stream processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information in [`Storage Analytics Logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging). Once you have enabled logging for your storage account, the information about operations performed against your storage account is saved in `$logs` blob container. It contains a bunch of CSV files. The information you're looking for is available in `<requester-ip-address>` field.

You can find more information about the schema of the data here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format.